# Sliding drawer layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i have an slider in my app that slide from left to right on button click .the xml code for the drawer is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pic4" >

<com.facebook.android.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/login_button"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textColor="@drawable/black" />

        <com.facebook.android.TransparentPanel
            android:id="@+id/popup_window"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="485dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:background="@drawable/black"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:showDividers="middle" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="378dp" >
        </ListView>


    </LinearLayout>

</com.facebook.android.TransparentPanel>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/show_popup_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/nextnew" />
```

the graphical layout show the slider perfectly but the only problem is that a white line as a border is also shown with the drawer. i want this to disappear or turn to black.
any tips will be appreciated .thanks